# How to find new height unit while switching the row height in react-grid-layout?

Tags: javascript, css, math, geometry, react-grid-layout

I'm using `react-grid-layout` and using `rowHeight` to set the height of a "grid item" **explicitly**.

Now i want to change the `rowHeight` to a smaller value (on click of a button).

****Current Behaviour:**** when the change is happened, all the tile heights are changed immediately **(*grid items are squished because of small heights*)**

****Expected Behaviour:**** the **tile height should be maintained** same as old row height, but the **height unit (h) should be increased.**

This seems easy without margin, but `react-grid-layout` uses a margin property. so that

> actual pixel height is (rowHeight * h) + (marginH * (h - 1).

> For example, with rowHeight=30, margin=[10,10] and a unit with height 4, the calculation is (30 * 4) + (10 * 3)
> [image]

https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#grid-item-heights-and-widths

Now i can calculate the old tile height.

But how can i find how many `h` i need, when i switch the row height from `rowHeight=30` to `rowHeight=10` and vice versa?

I have tried:

```js
          const newRowHeight = 10;
          const oldTileHeight = (rowHeight * item.h) + (gap * (item.h - 1));

          const newH = oldTileHeight / newRowHeight;
```

But this doesn't work! It gives me some extra height.

**Grid item
Old height: 320px;
New Height: 816px;**

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool maths! Here's what I've worked out:

```
/*
NOTES:
• For ease, I'll rename your "h" to "n"
• "H" stands for "height"
• "o" prefix means old, "n" prefix means new
*/

tileH = (oRowH * oN) + marginH * (oN - 1)
tileH = (nRowH * nN) + marginH * (nN - 1)

// Let's talk maths. We can turn those 2 to:
tileH = oN * (oRowH + marginH) - marginH
tileH = nN * (nRowH + marginH) - marginH

// Since tileH doesn't change:
nN * (nRowH + marginH) = oN * (oRowH + marginH)
nN = oN * (oRowH + marginH) / (nRowH + marginH)

// Or, alternatively:
nN * (nRowH + marginH) - marginH = tileH
nN * (nRowH + marginH) = tileH + marginH
nN = (tileH + marginH) / (nRowH + marginH)
```

That's a handful, but it *should* be correct. So:

```js
const newRowHeight = 10;
const oldTileHeight = (rowHeight * item.h) + (gap * (item.h - 1));
const newH = item.h * (rowHeight + gap) / (newRowHeight + gap);
// OR:
const newH = (oldTileHeight + gap) / (newRowHeight + gap);
```

So, your solution of `oldTileHeight / newRowHeight` is actually pretty close!

Hope it works :)

Comment: Wait, I sense something a bit wrong. Looking for it...

Comment: Alright. Realized my mistake, NOW it should work :)

Comment: wow! didn't realised we could compare equations and find out like this! this is cool, thank you very much!

Comment: @ShreyasJadhav yeah, maths can feel magical haha. You're welcome :) Does it work for you?